# Counting different items in dictionary

Tags: dictionary

Hi i have a bit of a problem: i am working on something to help me count the items in a dictionary, in this case the amount of different items that are stacked in it. E.g:

```
s = {"a": 34, "a": 23, "b": 2}
```

I tried doing it with `len()` and `.count()`, but it doesnt seem to present the right conclusion

So this is my dictionary and i need to count how many different items i actually have in it, so output has to be 2 in this case, cause a appears 2x.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

a key can only appear once in a dictionary...

`s = {"a": 34, "a": 23, "b": 2}` would just return `s = {"a": 23, "b": 2}`

Comment: Or `s = {"a": 34, "b": 2}` maybe... I guess it depends on what pair key,value is inserted first during initialization.